# Add youtube embed to woocommerce variations

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, embed, youtube

How to add youtube embed code/ embed shortcode to woocommerce product variations?
When I insert the shortcode [embed] also iframe code youtube and then saving the product variations the codes gone? Any tips and tricks to add video to product variations?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will automatically embed youtube if you just paste in the URL of the video. The [embed] shortcode is a relic from older times, you shouldn't need it anymore.

If you want to use the  embed code from YouTube you need to go into text editing mode in order to be able to paste the  code. If you paste it in Visual mode you'll just get the text of the code snippet, which won't do anything.

Comment: Yes I already tried to put  [embed] url [embed]  to product variation content but nothing happen on product variation description.

Comment: You shouldn't need [embed] [/embed] to make it work. However, it only works in rich text inputs, such as the main content field. Seems like I was a bit quick when answering your question.